# is it possible to get a "Cuts off" pattern in both ACF and PACF?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I understand how these patterns look in the ACF and PACF but i don't understand why (according to the literature) there cannot be a "cuts off" pattern in both ACF and PACF

[image]

Comment: White noise cuts out after zero lag in both the ACF and PACF.