# Is the plot "White noise"?

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

To stabilize the time series named "walk" (it is daily data), I applied log transformation and trend is removed through differencing and plot looks stationary.
Below the plot of acf and pacf of final time series is given.

[image: acf and pacf]

I read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395665/is-it-possible-to-get-a-cuts-off-pattern-in-both-acf-and-pacf) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108983/acf-and-pacf-plot-analysis) and unable to decide the order of the time series for modeling in ARIMA. May I know how to interpret this plot?

Comment: it is daily data and I assume now may be seasonality is there ?...

Comment: Yes, I accidentally pressed delete and my comment disappeared. Yes, there appears to be seasonality. You need to remove this by seasonal differencing or Add a regression variable that captures day of the week pattern.

Comment: @forecaster .. I tried as ns <- nsdiffs(walkts) and it says 0 number of differences required to make a given time series stationary. So it means no seasonality right? Also modArima <- auto.arima(walkts) returns ARIMA(0,1,0)(1,0,1)[7]